# can't load python tags table

Tags: python, ctags, tags

generating python tags with

```
for file in $(find -type f -regex ".+\\.\(py\)"); do etags -a $file; done
```

doesn't load at emacs with error

> path/TAGS is not a valid tags file

although other language i.e c works just fine,
and syntax of generated TAGS doesn't look odd!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with emacs configuration, it worked after re-installation.

with general regex

```
cd $1
rm -rf TAGS
for file in $(find $1 -type f -regex ".+\\.c?h?S?\(cpp\)?\(cxx\)?\(cc\)?\(hpp\)?\(hxx\)?\(hh\)?\(rb\)?\(go\)?\(js\)?\(py\)?\(java\)?" ); do
    echo "adding $file"
    etags -a $file
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the TAG file like this:

`find . -name "*.py" | xargs etags -a`

Then in .emacs file:

`(setq tags-table-list (list "/path/to/TAG/file/dir/"))`

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on which application is being used to generate the tags. Most, I belief, support an option specifically for use with Emacs. For Universal Ctags, there is the `-e` flag:

```
-e   Output tag file for use with Emacs.
```

To generate,

```
# -R to recurse, -e for Emacs
ctags -Re .
```

Load the result into Emacs with `M-x visit-tags-table`.